# Find the solution to this initial boundary value problem: $u_t = c^2 u_{xx}$, $-L < x < L$, $t>0$, $c>0$ ...

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

**Heat conduction in a thin circular ring (consider it as a rod, bent in the shape of a circular ring joining the two ends) of length $2L$, labeled $-L$ to $L$ leads to the equation $u_t = c^2 u_{xx}$, $-L < x < L$, $t>0$, $c>0$ with the initial condition $u(x,0) = f(x)$ and the periodic boundary conditions**
\begin{align}
u(-L,t) &= u(L,t)\\
u_{x}(-L,t) & = u_{x}(L,t) \hspace{0.5cm} t>0
\end{align}

**Find the solution to this initial boundary value problem.**

I'm trying to solve this initial condition problem. I solved the general case when the problem is
\begin{align}
u_t &= c^2 u_{xx} \hspace{0.5cm} 0 < x<L, \hspace{0.5cm} t>0, \hspace{0.5cm} c>0\\
u(x,0) &= f(x) \hspace{0.5cm} 0 \leq x \leq L \\
u_{x}(0,t) &= u_{x}(L,t) = 0 \hspace{0.5cm} t \geq 0
\end{align}
The conditions $u_{x}(0,t) = 0$, $u_{x}(L,t)=0$ are known as Neumann's conditions.
I solved the problem with Neumann conditions by separation of variables and obtained that

$$u(x,t) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_{n}\cos{\left(\frac{n \pi x}{L}\right)} e^{-\frac{n^{2}\pi^{2}c^2}{L^2}t}}$$

where $$ a_n = \frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}{f(x) \cos\left(\frac{n \pi x}{L}\right)dx}, \hspace{0.5cm} n\geq 0$$
However, the problem in my statement is very different from this problem that I solved. I don't know how to use this result in that problem, or maybe it should be done through variable separation, or using a different method, but I'm not sure about that. I have really spent a lot of time on this problem but I have not been able to achieve anything successful.
For this reason I would appreciate any help you can give me.

**An attempt:**

By separation of variables, let $u(x, t) = X (x) T (t)$. Then $u_t = XT'$and $u_{xx} = X''T$. Substituting in the original equation we have
$$XT' = c^2 X''T \Rightarrow \frac{T'}{c^2 T} = \frac{X''}{X} = - \lambda \hspace{0.4cm} \text{where} \hspace{0.4cm} \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$$  so we have the ordinary differential equation $X'' + \lambda X = 0$. The boundary conditions give:

\begin{align}
u(L,t) &= u(-L,t) = X(L)T(t) = X(-L)T(t) \Rightarrow X(L) = X(-L)\\
u_{x}(L,t) &= u_{x}(-L,t) = X'(L)T(t) = X'(-L)T(t) \Rightarrow X'(L) = X'(-L)
\end{align}

We have the problem:

\begin{cases}
X'' + \lambda X = 0\\
X(L) = X(-L) \hspace{0.8cm} (1)\\
X'(L) = X'(-L) \hspace{0.5cm} (2)
\end{cases}

Now if $\lambda > 0$, let's say $\lambda = k^2$ with $k> 0$, then
$$X'' + k^2 X = 0 \Rightarrow X(x) = a \cos(kx) + b \sin(kx)$$

Now, I need to use conditions (1) and (2) to find the numbers $a$ and $b$, but since these conditions are not homogeneous or are not an explicit function, then I have had a hard time continuing. How can I solve this?

Comment: You have obtained $u(x,t)$ as a series in terms of $f$ which is known. What else do you expect?

Comment: @DidierFelbacq The solution you mention is part of the problem with Newmann conditions, but I now need to solve the problem stated above with circular conduction. Really, the solution that I wrote in my comments I just wrote it thinking that I can solve the above problem through it. But I'm not sure. Or maybe I should use another way to solve it which I have not been able to do.

Comment: Ok I did not read carefully enough. Now you want a periodic function for $u(x,t)$ in the $x$ variable so you can look for a solution in the form of a Fourier series (i.e. variables separation), but since you do not have a Neumann condition, you need both $a_n$ and $b_n$ coefficients (i.e. for $\cos$ and $\sin$). Then you apply your initial condition and find that the coefficients are those of $f$.

Comment: It's **Neumann**, not "Newmann".

Comment: @DidierFelbacq I have written an attempt above on my problem, but I have had difficulty using the problem conditions.